# Why are both #seq & #ack setting 1 in the last ACK packet in 3-way-handshake?

Tags: tcp

I'm wondering why the third packet has been set seq=1 and ack=1 in 3-way-handshake.

```
 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 62, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    172.17.150.X.63996 > 172.17.150.Y.1234: Flags [S], cksum 0x9b6f (correct), seq 2029035340, win 65535, options [mss 1194,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3650496220 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    172.17.150.Y.1234 > 172.17.150.X.63996: Flags [S.], cksum 0x8546 (incorrect -> 0xec39), seq 1295300764, ack 2029035341, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2906721667 ecr 3650496220,nop,wscale 7], length 0
 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 62, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.17.150.X.63996 > 172.17.150.Y.1234: Flags [.], cksum 0x1184 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 2050, options [nop,nop,TS val 3650496229 ecr 2906721667], length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that tcpdump calculates sequence numbers and acknowledge numbers in TCP packets as relative. I can see the numbers in flow as absolute by using the -S option with tcpdump.